# Get object literal string with extra string embellishments around it

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I currently have an object literal in Typescript. Something like:

```
const MyNamesStrings = {
    a: {
        b: "hello",
        c: "bye"
    }
    d: {
        e: "qwerty"
    }
}
```

But I want to wrap them in some strings every time I access them. The strings are the same, and would look very ugly and repetitive if it's in the literal. This would allow me to have a much easier time maintaining the strings.

I want to create a `MyNames` class that acts like a proxy with the functionality to do this:

```
const ab = MyNames.a.b //"[${hello}]" where the extra characters surround the text.
const ac = MyNames.a.c //"[${bye}]"
```

Is this feasible in Javascript/Typescript? If it's not, I can always just do it in more mundane ways.

Comment: In the future, please [make some attempt at doing this yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the behavior you describe, you could use an actual [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), if your JavaScript engine supports ECMAScript 2015 or later.  This might be overkill for your use case; if `MyNamesStrings` is immutable, a one-time transformation from `MyNamesStrings` to `MyNames` would be more efficient.  But let's assume you do need a proxy.  Here's one way to implement it:

```
function makeStringWrappingProxy<T extends object>(t: T): T {
  return new Proxy(t, {
    get<K extends keyof T>(target: T, prop: K) {
      const val = target[prop];
      if (typeof val === 'string') {
        return '[${' + val + '}]';
      } else if (typeof val === 'object') {
        return makeStringWrappingProxy(val as T[K] & object);
      } else {
        return val;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The idea is return a proxy which that intercepts all property retrievals to the object.  If you are getting a string property, return the wrapped string instead.  If you are getting an object property, return a proxy for that property instead (this allows you to drill down into properties of properties and still see them wrapped). Otherwise, just return the property.

Let's see it in action:

```
const MyNames = makeStringWrappingProxy(MyNamesStrings);
const ab = MyNames.a.b //"[${hello}]" as expected
const ac = MyNames.a.c //"[${bye}]" as expected as well.
```

So it works!  Again, this assumes you actually want to do it this way.  Proxies aren't particularly performant (each property access kicks off function calls), backward compatible (ES5 doesn't support it), or intuitive (you can modify a property but when you read the property afterward it isn't what you set it to).  It's up to you.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

basically you could do a custom getter function and instead of accessing to `MyNamesStrings.a.b` you can do `MyNamesStrings.propGetter('a.b')`

```js
var MyNamesStrings = {
  a: {
    b: "hello",
    c: "bye"
  },
  d: {
    e: "qwerty"
  },
  propGetter: function(loc, start = "[${", end = "}]") {
    var split = loc.split('.');
    var value = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      if (value) {
        value = value[split[i]];
      }else{
          //stop looping because the previous value doesn't exist.
          break;
      }
    }
    return value ? start + value + end : undefined;
  }
}

var result = MyNamesStrings.propGetter('a.b');
var result2 = MyNamesStrings.propGetter('d.e');
var result3 = MyNamesStrings.propGetter('f.g.h.i');

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```